# SHarepoint Search 2010 - XSL Code Customization

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, xslt, search-results, enterprise-search

I need to display the image preview on my search result by replacing the code for the search-icon as below XSL code:

img align="absmiddle" src="http://site/image/123.jpg" border="0"  alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}"

for my testing i replaced the {imageurl} by a static path to display the image and its working ....  please help to find the parameter and replaced by the src"{imageurl}"  and display the image inside my search result ??

regards,

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion is better if you start to debug your XSLT.

You could download the XML generated by the Search Result and use Visual Studio to made a good XSLT.

In this link you can read how to use VS2010 to debug the XSLT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255605.aspx

And in this links you can find a step-by-step guide: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-add-custom-value-in-search-core.html

http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.it/2012/04/how-to-modify-sharepoints-result-page.html